# PHP : upload video to youtube using link[direct link] using curl

Tags: codeigniter, curl, youtube

Video is uploaded to youtube if I use the form below. I am able to fetch the response from youtube after login and adopt the response in the form below.

```
 <form action="<?php echo( $response->url ); ?>?nexturl=<?php echo( urlencode( $nexturl ) ); ?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <p class="block">
            <label>Upload Video</label>
            <span class="youtube-input">
                <input id="file" type="file" name="file" />
            </span>                        
        </p>
        <input type="hidden" name="token" value="<?php echo( $response->token ); ?>"/>
        <input type="submit" value="Upload Video" />
    </form>
```

But If try to do the same with curl as below then it doesnt work .. Any suggestions ??

```
$file_name_with_full_path = $video_path; //$video_path is like /path/to/abc.mp4
$post = array('file'=>'@'.$file_name_with_full_path, 'token' => $response->token,);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$response->url."?nexturl=".urlencode($nexturl));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close ($ch);
echo $result;
die();
```

echo result given bool(false). Please tell whats wrong in this . Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you tell us what `curl_error($ch)` returns?

Comment: @dodo it return blank

Comment: Are you sure curl is working on your system?